# Issue with VSCode Tab Handler

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

Here is a quick GIF of the little issue i'm having..

https://i.gyazo.com/2d1dfdc9f92446578a4aa45bbd75ec2d.gif

It seems similar to

[Issue with TAB and ENTER in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000189/issue-with-tab-and-enter-in-vscode)

Just when I go to tab into the next portion of my snippet, the handler gets caught up on other similar word matches on the page instead of simply moving onto the next part of my snippet.. This is a deal breaker for me as I NEED to press escape every time before pressing tab just to wright a simple foreach loop. (Since there is always a plural form of the variable in foreach loops..)

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution for me was to add use the

```
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": x
```

Adding 400ms(I'd adjust it for your typing speed) delay so I can type foreach (wait a brief moment to tab then quickly fill in my predefined snipped like I wanted :p)

Comment: Anybody who stumbles acroess this is too late. Just wanted to let you all know this is why VSCode will not, and never likely work for a majority of developers.. I suggest heavily scripting atom to fit every need possible otherwise sublime text 3 is my favorite in terms of personal preference.